# Create Chrome profiles without launching Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, command-line, command

This has its use in automating creation of new Chrome Profiles.  I am using windows and this tends to work except that it launches Chrome.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

I am just wondering if there is a way to do this so that I can create profiles faster as it uses a lot of CPU this way.  Firefox creates profiles without launching them.

These profiles will be later used in Selenium

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use NodeJS and chrome headless to automate this. Please look at the below url

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

function createChromeProfile(profileName) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({
    // port: 9222, // Uncomment to force a specific port of your choice.
    chromeFlags: [
      '--profile-directory="' + profileName + '"',
      '--window-size=412,732',
      '--disable-gpu',
      '--headless'
    ]
  });
}

createChromeProfile("Profile 1").then(chrome => {
  console.log(`Chrome debuggable on port: ${chrome.port}`);
  ...
  chrome.kill();
});
```

Comment: I get a lot of unresolved references in Python 3. It'd be difficult to do this if I wanted to create 100 profiles for Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I have never used NodeJs. I use python in Pycharm.  Hummm...  Pycharm supports NodeJs through an extension...

Comment: It would be easier with NodeJS as the code is readily available